# Sql Query: Union All with Top

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, union-all

I want to get a combined output from two select statements.

First select returns the object of a certain index. 
Second select returns the closest Object.

```
  declare @h geometry select @h = Geom from obj where ObjectIndex = 15054
  select ObjectIndex, Geom.STDistance(@h) from obj where ObjectIndex = 15054 
  union all
  select top( 1) ObjectIndex, Geom.STDistance(@h) from  obj WITH(index(idx_Spatial)) where Geom.STDistance(@h) < 0.0004 
  and ObjectLayerName = 'Up_Layer' order by Geom.STDistance(@h)
```

[image: First Query]

Unfortunately, the second statement returns the wrong object. I expected the closest object, but it returns the second closest instance.
However, when I only perform the second select statement it returns the right object.

```
 select top( 1) ObjectIndex, Geom.STDistance(@h) from  obj WITH(index(idx_Spatial)) where Geom.STDistance(@h) < 0.0004 
  and ObjectLayerName = 'Up_Layer' order by Geom.STDistance(@h)
```

[image: 2. Query without Union]

Thanks for help.

Comment: I expect if you put the second query in a subquery you'll get the result you expect (`... union all select ObjectIndex, STDistance fom (top 1 ... order by Geom.STDistance(@h)`). Make sure to give your second column an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Order by` will be applied after the `UNION`, try something like this

```
DECLARE @h GEOMETRY

SELECT @h = Geom
FROM   obj
WHERE  ObjectIndex = 15054

SELECT ObjectIndex,
       Geom.Stdistance(@h) dist
FROM   obj
WHERE  ObjectIndex = 15054
UNION ALL
SELECT ObjectIndex,
       dist
FROM  (SELECT TOP( 1) ObjectIndex,
                      Geom.Stdistance(@h) AS dist
       FROM   obj WITH(INDEX(idx_Spatial))
       WHERE  Geom.Stdistance(@h) < 0.0004
              AND ObjectLayerName = 'Up_Layer'
       ORDER  BY Geom.Stdistance(@h)) a
ORDER  BY dist
```